# python parse string and turn into dictionary input

Tags: python, string, dictionary

this is my list:

```
list1 = ('/a/b/c/Hello1/d/e','/a/b/c/Hello2/d/e','/a/b/c/Hello3/d/e')
list2 = []

for x in list1:
    y = x.split('/')[4]
    list2.append(y)

list2 = ['Hello1', 'Hello2', 'Hello3']
```

Now I want to create a dictionary where Hello[1-3] is my key and the **corresponding** string '/a/b/c/Hello[1-3]/d/e' is the value.
How can I connect key and value in python. I am sure this is fairly easy, but I don't know.

Thank you.

Comment: any attempt at splitting will fail if your path slightly changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to achieve this.

```
>>> {s.split('/')[4] : s for s in list1}
{'Hello2': '/a/b/c/Hello2/d/e',
 'Hello3': '/a/b/c/Hello3/d/e',
 'Hello1': '/a/b/c/Hello1/d/e'}
```

Comment: But only if the list of values is structured exactly the way the OP suggests. A more general solution is to use zip().

Comment: @dylrei I'm not sure I follow. The order of the list is irrelevant, this solution will guarantee that the key corresponds to the value it originally came from.

Comment: Thank you Cyber! That works perfectly. @dylrei - would sorted(list1) and sorted(list2) work? Otherwise I am not sure what would be the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not the order, the structure. In the example, the key is contained in the value. I'm not sure OP was actually asking how to extract that, but rather how to fuse two lists into a dict.

Comment: @dylrei I know, that is what this does! This actually extracts the key **and** creates a `dict`. Look at the output of your solution, then at my solution. They are the exact same! This is literally just another way to do exactly what you did, but more concisely!

Comment: @Cyber I see how your solution works, and it answers the question perfectly. I just thought there was a very good chance that the question is over-specified and that the OP actually wants to know how to zip() two lists. Apparently not, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the same number of elements in list1 and list2:

```
dict(zip(list2, list1))
```